# Error while installing pyramid in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyramid

I tried to install pyramid with this command:

```
pip install pyramid
```

But got these warnings:

> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
>   warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
>   warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution

Due to this, I am getting errors while performing other installations. Can you please help me solve this problem?

> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

Comment: These warnings are usually ignorable, especially for Python libraries that don't require C extensions, like Pyramid - what's the error in the other installation?

Comment: Those are *warnings*. What **errors** are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should include the version of your Python in your question.

Second, it's not clear whether you created a virtual environment using `virtualenv` or `pyvenv` depending on your Python version, then installed packages into the virtual environment. It's a really good idea™ to do so.

Without those details, the "tried and true" and recommended process to install Pyramid can be found in its [documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-unix). The installation steps include the following.

- Install a supported Python and a Python interpreter.
- Install setuptools.
- Install virtualenv.
- Create a virtual environment.
- Install Pyramid into the virtual environment.

If you have Python 3.2 or greater (preferably 3.4), then an alternative installation method would be a simple three lines, extracted from [TryPyramid](http://trypyramid.com/).

```
pyvenv myproject
cd myproject
bin/pip install pyramid waitress
```

Comment: At present, I am using python 2.7.6

Comment: Did you follow the recommended process in the Pyramid documentation? Here again is the link, this time without markdown markup. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#installing-unix